# How could i get rid off 500 error vercel app

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, vercel

I recently deployed my express project to [vercel.com](https://vercel.com/). But for some reason I often get a 500 error when making HTTP requests, for example, a request for a page or a request for an image (here is the link, you can check it yourself [wowcutegift.com](https://wowcutegift.com/)).

For example, I can get an error 500, then I refresh the page and there is no longer this error, then I refresh it again and it appears again.

```
[GET] /
js:15:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10) {
  reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'ReplicaSetNoPrimary',
    servers: Map(3) {
      'cluster0-shard-00-00.admjq.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription],
      'cluster0-shard-00-01.admjq.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription],
      'cluster0-shard-00-02.admjq.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription]
    },
    stale: false,
    compatible: true,
    heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
    localThresholdMS: 15,
    setName: 'atlas-wz86q8-shard-0',
    logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: undefined
  }
}
2022-03-24T09:25:22.973Z    d5a670eb-5b1f-4d0d-8886-056d2fe8fe72    ERROR   Unhandled Promise Rejection     {"errorType":"Runtime.UnhandledPromiseRejection","errorMessage":"MongooseServerSelectionError: Could not connect to any servers in your MongoDB Atlas cluster. One common reason is that you're trying to access the database from an IP that isn't whitelisted. Make sure your current IP address is on your Atlas cluster's IP whitelist: https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/security-whitelist/","reason":{"errorType":"MongooseServerSelectionError","errorMessage":"Could not connect to any servers in your MongoDB Atlas cluster. One common reason is that you're trying to access the database from an IP that isn't whitelisted. Make sure your current IP address is on your Atlas cluster's IP whitelist: https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/security-whitelist/","message":"Could not connect to any servers in your MongoDB Atlas cluster. One common reason is that you're trying to access the database from an IP that isn't whitelisted. Make sure your current IP address is on your Atlas cluster's IP whitelist: https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/security-whitelist/","reason":{"type":"ReplicaSetNoPrimary","servers":{},"stale":false,"compatible":true,"heartbeatFrequencyMS":10000,"localThresholdMS":15,"setName":"atlas-wz86q8-shard-0"},"stack":["MongooseServerSelectionError: Could not connect to any servers in your MongoDB Atlas cluster. One common reason is that you're trying to access the database from an IP that isn't whitelisted. Make sure your current IP address is on your Atlas cluster's IP whitelist: https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/security-whitelist/","    at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (/var/task/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:807:32)","    at /var/task/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:340:10","    at /var/task/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/promiseOrCallback.js:32:5","    at new Promise (<anonymous>)","    at promiseOrCallback (/var/task/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/promiseOrCallback.js:31:10)","    at Mongoose._promiseOrCallback (/var/task/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:1140:10)","    at Mongoose.connect (/var/task/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:339:20)","    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/index.js:15:10)","    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)","    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)"]},"promise":{},"stack":["Runtime.UnhandledPromiseRejection: MongooseServerSelectionError: Could not connect to any servers in your MongoDB Atlas cluster. One common reason is that you're trying to access the database from an IP that isn't whitelisted. Make sure your current IP address is on your Atlas cluster's IP whitelist: https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/security-whitelist/","    at process.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/index.js:35:15)","    at process.emit (events.js:412:35)","    at processPromiseRejections (internal/process/promises.js:245:33)","    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:96:32)"]}
[ERROR] [1648113922974] LAMBDA_RUNTIME Failed to post handler success response. HTTP response code: 400.
RequestId: 807a69b0-c3c4-4ba3-ac2d-4b1dd364a152 Error: Runtime exited with error: exit status 128
Runtime.ExitError
```

There is also this line

`One common reason is that you're trying to access the database from an IP that isn't whitelisted. Make sure your current IP address is on your Atlas cluster's IP whitelist: https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/security-whitelist/`

I added the server's IP to the whitelist, also tried to open access for all IPs by adding 0.0.0.0 and it still did not help.

If anyone has come across this problem please let me know. Maybe it's because I have a free version of MongoDB or vercel. I used to have an application on Heroku and had no such problems, although the databases were the same and free.

Comment: Did you find any solution to this error? I am having this one as well, it works fine most of the time but randomly fails with this MongooseServerSelectionError error :(

Comment: Jeremy, i didn't find solution. I've switched to heroku. You can write to support, but you will wait a long time for an answer, it's easier to just use another server.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76973164/intermittent-unhandled-promise-rejection-mongoserverselectionerror-connection I am also facing similar issue on vercel. Looks like issue is from vercel side and not mongodb side?