# Intermittent Unhandled Promise Rejection - MongoServerSelectionError: connection timed out

Tags: node.js, mongodb, vercel, atlas

I am getting below error randomly.
Here is my stack

- App deployed on vercel is talking to Atlas mongodb (free tier)
- Nodejs - 18.16.1
- nextjs 13
- mongodb package version - 5.8.1

```
ERROR   Unhandled Promise Rejection     {"errorType":"Runtime.UnhandledPromiseRejection","errorMessage":"MongoServerSelectionError: connection timed out","reason":{"errorType":"MongoServerSelectionError","errorMessage":"connection timed out","reason":{"type":"ReplicaSetNoPrimary","servers":{},"stale":false,"compatible":true,"heartbeatFrequencyMS":10000,"localThresholdMS":15,"setName":"Cluster0-shard-0","maxElectionId":null,"maxSetVersion":null,"commonWireVersion":0,"logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes":null},"stack":["MongoServerSelectionError: connection timed out","    at Timeout._onTimeout (/var/task/node_modules/mongodb/lib/sdam/topology.js:278:38)","    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:569:17)","    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:512:7)"]},"promise":{},"stack":["Runtime.UnhandledPromiseRejection: MongoServerSelectionError: connection timed out","    at process.<anonymous> (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1186:17)","    at process.emit (node:events:525:35)","    at emit (node:internal/process/promises:149:20)","    at processPromiseRejections (node:internal/process/promises:283:27)","    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:32)"]}
[ERROR] [1692852863980] LAMBDA_RUNTIME Failed to post handler success response. Http response code: 400.
RequestId: 971d9da3-a51d-4511-a561-22d5702be848 Error: Runtime exited with error: exit status 128
```

When this error occurs, server responds with http 500 error code.

Can someone tell me why this would happen? Is it due to free tier of Atlas Mongodb?

Below code shows how I am connecting to mongodb.
Clientpromise is being imported and then used to do db operations in other files.

```
import { MongoClient } from "mongodb";

//mongodb+srv://sjhfjhfjhf/ongodb.net/awesomedb?serverSelectionTimeoutMS=60000
const uri = process.env.MONGODB_URI;
const options = {
  //useUnifiedTopology: true,
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  serverSelectionTimeoutMS: 59000,
};

let client;
let clientPromise;

if (!process.env.MONGODB_URI) {
  throw new Error("Please add your Mongo URI to .env.local");
}

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "development") {
  // In development mode, use a global variable so that the value
  // is preserved across module reloads caused by HMR (Hot Module Replacement).
  if (!global._mongoClientPromise) {
    client = new MongoClient(uri, options);
    global._mongoClientPromise = client.connect();
  }
  clientPromise = global._mongoClientPromise;
} else {
  // In production mode, it's best to not use a global variable.
  client = new MongoClient(uri, options);
  clientPromise = client.connect();
}

// Export a module-scoped MongoClient promise. By doing this in a
// separate module, the client can be shared across functions.
export default clientPromise;
```

Here is how I am firing the query

```
import { ObjectId } from 'mongodb';
import clientPromise from '../../lib/mongodb'
import { connectToDatabase, slugify } from './blog';

export async function saveAdToMongoDB(adObj) {
  try {
    const collection = (await clientPromise).db().collection("ads");  
    let catslug = slugify(adObj.businessCategory)
    let slug = slugify( adObj.businessName + "-" + adObj.city + "-" + catslug)
    adObj.slug = slug ;
    adObj.catslug = catslug;
    let advertisementObject = {...adObj, status:"pending",image:""}
    let result = await collection.insertOne(advertisementObject);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error("Failed to save ad to MongoDB:", err);
  } 
}
```

I upgraded mongodb and nextjs packages but it did not help. Most of other solutions on internet are talking about firewall and ip whitelisting. But I do not think that's causing the issue.

Comment: Have allowed access to your atlas cluster: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/security/ip-access-list/#add-ip-access-list-entries?

Comment: @robin-thomas I have given access to cluster from all ip addresses. If this was the issue, I would not have been able to connect to mongodb even once. Please note that this issue is happening randomly.

Comment: Can someone answer this question. it is mission critical issue for me!!

Answer (score 1):

It's a combination of limitations of free Atlas tier and Vercel hosting.

When you exhaust 500 connections quota, you get connection timeout. See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/76905054/1110423 for details.

Comment: will the reason type in this case be `"type": "ReplicaSetNoPrimary",`?

Comment: @dododo, the root cause is "MongoServerSelectionError: connection timed out". It's just happened that the first thing the driver does is connects to the replicaset to find the primary member.  I see your point and do agree that the answer is a bit speculative. Atlas monitoring of active connections at the time of the error would be the best proof.

Comment: `MongoServerSelectionError: connection timed out` itself usually means not much without analyzing the cluster state in the error message. Idk, whether reason you mention about atlas limitation can generate `ReplicaSetNoPrimary` issue, I would not expect so, but hard to say for sure. I agree that we need more details, first of all from the server logs, to say something for sure. I've added my answer with some more details :)

Comment: @dododo, you're right. I wouldn't speculate if it wasn't for vercel + M0 Atlas combo and the fact that the OP is "getting below error randomly".  These 2 just don't play together, and the symptoms are typical to the set up.

Comment: I'm getting this exact issue, same setup.  When it happens I only have about 30 connections as seen by Atlas.

Comment: @gunygoogoo A good half of javascriptish errors say Unhandled Promise Rejection and return "http 500 error code" on the surface. It doesn't make them "exact this issue", and tbh this issue does not provide much more details. As mentioned in comments M0+vercel is most likely cause, but by no means the only. I am more than happy to help with alternatives if you ask your own question. As dododo mentioned details are the key, as generally intermittent network errors require debugging and log analysis to find the root cause.

Comment: @AlexBlex  I got the exact same issue. Just created a SO question with server logs and database logs a few hours ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78168286/nextauth-js-error-next-autherrorclient-fetch-error-unexpected-token?noredirect=1#comment137808613_78168286 I'll do anything to fix this.

Comment: @Reinier68 As much as I'd love to benefit from `I'll do anything` thing, I cannot do more than I put in the answer there. It doesn't fix the problem per se, but I hope it helps to dig deeper in the right direction and resolve it eventually.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error as you, and was able to fix it by using a drop-in replacement for `clientPromise` sourced from the mongodb-starter repo by Vercel.

https://github.com/vercel/mongodb-starter/blob/main/lib/mongodb.ts

I previously had the same `clientPromise` as you, but since I've updated to the Singleton approach, I haven't seen the error on my Vercel production deployment.

Hopefully this helps, I specifically signed up just in hope of saving someone the day I spent solving this issue.