# Getting ReplicaSetNoPrimary error for M0 cluster when using Django with MongoEngine

Tags: python, django, mongodb, crud, mongoengine

I am using django with mongoengine. I am writing the following in the settings.py file:

```
from mongoengine import connect
URI = 'mongodb+srv://myusername:mypassword@cluster0.5apjp.mongodb.net/django?retryWrites=true&w=majority&ssl=false'
connect(host=URI)
```

After that, I have a model as follows:

```
from mongoengine import Document, StringField
class User(Document):
    first_name = StringField(max_length=50)
    last_name = StringField(max_length=50)

    meta = {
        'collection': 'users'
    }
```

I have a view as follows:

```
def adduser(request):
    userDict = json.loads(request.body)
    newUser = User(first_name=userDict['firstName'],last_name=userDict['lastName'])
    newUser.save()
    return HttpResponse('user added')
```

When this view function is called, I get an error as follows:

```
ServerSelectionTimeoutError(
pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: cluster0-shard-00-02.5apjp.mongodb.net:27017: 
connection closed (configured timeouts: socketTimeoutMS: 20000.0ms, connectTimeoutMS: 
20000.0ms),cluster0-shard-00-01.5apjp.mongodb.net:27017: connection closed (configured timeouts:
 socketTimeoutMS: 20000.0ms, connectTimeoutMS: 20000.0ms),cluster0-shard-00-00.5apjp.mongodb.net:27017: 
connection closed (configured timeouts: socketTimeoutMS: 20000.0ms, connectTimeoutMS: 20000.0ms),
 Timeout: 30s, Topology Description: <TopologyDescription id: 65c3bdc13c9136a1191890e1, 
topology_type: ReplicaSetNoPrimary, servers: [<ServerDescription ('cluster0-shard-00-00.5apjp.mongodb.net', 27017) 
server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=AutoReconnect('cluster0-shard-00-00.5apjp.mongodb.net:27017: 
connection closed (configured timeouts: socketTimeoutMS: 20000.0ms, connectTimeoutMS: 20000.0ms)')>, 
<ServerDescription ('cluster0-shard-00-01.5apjp.mongodb.net', 27017) 
server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=AutoReconnect('cluster0-shard-00-01.5apjp.mongodb.net:27017: 
connection closed (configured timeouts: socketTimeoutMS: 20000.0ms, connectTimeoutMS: 20000.0ms)')>, 
<ServerDescription ('cluster0-shard-00-02.5apjp.mongodb.net', 27017) 
server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=AutoReconnect('cluster0-shard-00-02.5apjp.mongodb.net:27017: 
connection closed (configured timeouts: socketTimeoutMS: 20000.0ms, 
connectTimeoutMS: 20000.0ms)')>]>
[07/Feb/2024 23:02:38] "POST /user/adduser HTTP/1.1" 500 115166
```

I am using a mongodb free M0 cluster with database named as 'django' and collection named as 'users'.

If I use a non-SRV URI string like localhost:27017, it works fine. But when I use a SRV URI, its giving me this error.

Moreover, I have added 0.0.0.0/0 in the IP access list of Network Access tab of MongoDB Atlas UI.

Please help me to get rid of this error so that I can proceed with basic CRUD operations on MongoDB using Django with MongoEngine.

Comment: `mongodb://localhost:27017` connects to a MongoDB running on your local machine, whereas `mongodb+srv://myusername:mypassword@cluster0.5apjp.mongodb.net` connects to a MongoDB cloud service. They are fundamentally different.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Can you please tell me why I am getting the error. MongoDB support could not give me a solution.

Comment: Maybe your network firewall blocks it. Can you connect with other tools, e.g. mongo shell `mongosh` or Mongo Compass?

Comment: @dododo Thanks but support personnel from MongoDB have already inspected my project, database and cluster. They all seem ok. So, am still waiting for someone to provide a concrete solution.

Comment: if you use vercel, then this might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/76992556/9492730

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course I need to remove `ssl=false`. But that does not fix my issue. I was getting SSL certificate error after that. From the MongoDB Developer Community, I got to know that my OS system certs are out of date and need to be updated. One can update them or can override them via `certifi` as follows:

```
python -m pip install --upgrade certifi
```

And then in my settings.py,

```
import certifi
from mongoengine import connect
URI = 'mongodb+srv://...'
connect(host=URI, tlsCAFile=certifi.where())
```

Now it is working fine completely.

Answer (score 2):

MongoDB Atlas server require all client connections to use SSL/TLS.

The mongodb+srv protocol implicitly enables TLS.

Putting `ssl=false` in connection string override the implicit default, resulting in an attempt to connect without using SSL/TLS.

Since non-encrypted connections are not permitted, the server immediately closes the connection without a reply, which looks a lot like a network error after connecting.

Remove `ssl=false` from the connection string to connect.

Comment: I have tried connecting after removing ssl=false. But still the same error.

Comment: You are still getting "connection closed" for each of the nodes in the list?

Comment: I have contacted MongoDB Support and they have given me the following solution. Now it is working fine.