# NextAuth.js Error: [next-auth][error][CLIENT_FETCH_ERROR] Unexpected token '<' "

Tags: node.js, mongodb, next.js, next.js13, next-auth

I am using `"next-auth": "^4.24.7"`. In development, everything is working perfectly. In production (deployed on Vercel), something weird is happening. When I refresh my website, about 1/4 of the time, I get a `[next-auth][error][CLIENT_FETCH_ERROR]` error, the other 75% of the time, I just get a status code 200 or 304 and the session is returned (or an empty object if I am not logged in).

This is the error I am getting:

GET https://example.com/api/auth/session 500 (Internal Server Error)

{
"error": {
"message": "Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON",
"stack": "SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON",
"name": "SyntaxError"
},
"url": "/api/auth/session",
"message": "Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON",
"client": true
}

This is my complete `/pages/api/auth/[...nextauth].js` file:

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import EmailProvider from "next-auth/providers/email";
import CredentialsProviders from "next-auth/providers/credentials";
import { MongoDBAdapter } from "@auth/mongodb-adapter";
const sgMail = require("@sendgrid/mail");

import { connectToMongoDB } from "@/config/db";
import clientPromise from "./lib/mongodb";
import User from "@/models/User";
import Document from "@/models/Document";

import { document } from "@/application/utils/document";
import { documentTemplates } from "@/application/utils/documentTemplates";

sgMail.setApiKey(process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY);

export const authOptions = {
  secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
  adapter: MongoDBAdapter(clientPromise),
  providers: [
    CredentialsProviders({
      name: "Email",
      credentials: {
        email: { label: "Email", type: "email", placeholder: "john@doe.com" },
      },
      authorize: async (credentials) => {
        console.log("Authorizing user", credentials.email);
        await connectToMongoDB().catch((err) => {
          throw new Error(err);
        });

        const { template, givenName, lastName, email } = credentials;

        const existingUser = await User.findOne({ email: email.toLowerCase().trim() });

        if (existingUser) {
          throw new Error("UserExists");
        } else {
          const newUser = await User.create({
            firstName: givenName,
            lastName: lastName,
            email: email.toLowerCase().trim(),
          });

          if (newUser) {
            document.documentTemplate = template;

            const templateOptions = documentTemplates.find((dt) => dt.name === template);
            document.templateOptions = templateOptions;

            const newDocument = await Document.create({
              documentData: document,
            });

            newUser.documents.push(newDocument._id);
            await newUser.save();

            newUser.documentId = newDocument._id.toString();
            newUser.userId = newUser._id.toString();

            return newUser;
          } else {
            return null; // return null to reject sign in attempt
          }
        }
      },
    }),
    EmailProvider({
      from: process.env.EMAIL_FROM,
      sendVerificationRequest: async ({ identifier: email, url, provider: { from } }) => {
        console.log("Email");
        const { host } = new URL(url);

        console.log(url);

        await connectToMongoDB().catch((err) => {
          throw new Error(err);
        });

        const user = await User.findOne({ email: email.toLowerCase().trim() });

        // logic for sending login mail with sendgrid
      },
    }),
  ],
  session: {
    strategy: "jwt",
  },
  pages: {
    signIn: "/app/auth/sign-in",
  },
  callbacks: {
    jwt: async ({ token, user }) => {
      console.log("CALLBACK JWT TOKEM: ", token.email);
      if (user?.documentId) {
        token.documentId = user.documentId;
      }
      if (user) {
        token.userId = user.id;
        token.user = user;
        token.firstName = user.firstName;
        token.lastName = user.lastName;
      }
      return token;
    },
    session: async ({ session, token }) => {
      console.log("CALLBACK SESSIONS: ", session.user.email);
      if (token?.documentId) {
        session.user.documentId = token.documentId;
      }
      if (token?.userId) {
        session.user.userId = token.userId;
      }
      session.user.firstName = token.firstName;
      session.user.lastName = token.lastName;
      return session;
    },
  },
};

export default NextAuth(authOptions);
```

As per the [documentation](https://authjs.dev/reference/adapter/mongodb), I added a /pages/api/auth/lib/mongodb.js file:

```
import { MongoClient } from "mongodb";

import { MONGODB_URI } from "@/config/db";

console.log("MONGODB_URI TEST in mongodb.js: ", MONGODB_URI);

const uri = MONGODB_URI;
const options = {
  serverSelectionTimeoutMS: 7500,
};

let client;
let clientPromise;

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "dev") {
  console.log("development mode");
  if (!global._mongoClientPromise) {
    client = new MongoClient(uri, options);
    global._mongoClientPromise = client.connect();
  }
  clientPromise = global._mongoClientPromise;
} else {
  console.log("production mode");
  client = new MongoClient(uri, options);
  clientPromise = client.connect();
}

export default clientPromise;
```

This is my _app.js with the SessionProvider:

```
import { SessionProvider } from "next-auth/react";
import { appWithTranslation } from "next-i18next";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import "../application/locales/translations.js";
import "@fontsource/inter";
import "@fontsource/inter/300.css";
import "@fontsource/inter/500.css";
import "@fontsource/inter/700.css";
import "@/styles/globals.css";

import MainLayout from "@/layouts/MainLayout";
import AppLayout from "@/layouts/AppLayout";
import DocumentLayout from "@/layouts/DocumentLayout";

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps: { session, ...pageProps } }) {
  const router = useRouter();

  const getLayout = (pathname) => {
    if (
      pathname.startsWith("/app/documents/") ||
      (pathname.startsWith("/app/letters/") && pathname.includes("/edit"))
    ) {
      return DocumentLayout;
    }
    if (pathname.startsWith("/app")) {
      return AppLayout;
    }
    return MainLayout;
  };

  const Layout = getLayout(router.pathname);

  return (
    <SessionProvider session={session}>
      <Layout>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </Layout>
    </SessionProvider>
  );
}

export default appWithTranslation(MyApp);
```

Now, a few important bits of information:

- First of all, I use `"next": "13.3.0"` with the pages router.
- Secondly, I use `next-i18next` with a multi domain setup (don't know if that's relevant).
- I did not set a `NEXTAUTH_URL` as this is [not required](https://next-auth.js.org/deployment#vercel) when deployed to Vercel.
- I do have a `NEXTAUTH_SECRET` set as a environment variable.
- Lastly, this is the error message straight from the Vercel logs:

```
MongoServerSelectionError: Server selection timed out after 7500 ms
    at EventTarget.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/mongodb/lib/sdam/topology.js:289:34)
    at [nodejs.internal.kHybridDispatch] (node:internal/event_target:786:20)
    at EventTarget.dispatchEvent (node:internal/event_target:721:26)
    at abortSignal (node:internal/abort_controller:369:10)
    at TimeoutController.abort (node:internal/abort_controller:403:5)
    at Timeout.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:976:92)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:569:17)
    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:512:7) {
  reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'ReplicaSetNoPrimary',
    servers: Map(1) {
      'db-cv-0fe05b80.mongo.ondigitalocean.com:27017' => [ServerDescription]
    },
    stale: false,
    compatible: true,
    heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
    localThresholdMS: 15,
    setName: 'db-cv?directConnection=true',
    maxElectionId: null,
    maxSetVersion: null,
    commonWireVersion: 0,
    logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null
  },
  code: undefined,
  [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(0) {}
}
2024-03-15T18:36:14.302Z    71c08204-7bbc-4a86-8d3b-f8f4b937b929    ERROR   Unhandled Promise Rejection     {"errorType":"Runtime.UnhandledPromiseRejection","errorMessage":"MongoServerSelectionError: Server selection timed out after 7500 ms","reason":{"errorType":"MongoServerSelectionError","errorMessage":"Server selection timed out after 7500 ms","reason":{"type":"ReplicaSetNoPrimary","servers":{},"stale":false,"compatible":true,"heartbeatFrequencyMS":10000,"localThresholdMS":15,"setName":"db-cv?directConnection=true","maxElectionId":null,"maxSetVersion":null,"commonWireVersion":0,"logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes":null},"stack":["MongoServerSelectionError: Server selection timed out after 7500 ms","    at EventTarget.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/mongodb/lib/sdam/topology.js:289:34)","    at [nodejs.internal.kHybridDispatch] (node:internal/event_target:786:20)","    at EventTarget.dispatchEvent (node:internal/event_target:721:26)","    at abortSignal (node:internal/abort_controller:369:10)","    at TimeoutController.abort (node:internal/abort_controller:403:5)","    at Timeout.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:976:92)","    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:569:17)","    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:512:7)"]},"promise":{},"stack":["Runtime.UnhandledPromiseRejection: MongoServerSelectionError: Server selection timed out after 7500 ms","    at process.<anonymous> (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1276:17)","    at process.emit (node:events:529:35)","    at emit (node:internal/process/promises:149:20)","    at processPromiseRejections (node:internal/process/promises:283:27)","    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:32)"]}
[ERROR] [1710527774303] LAMBDA_RUNTIME Failed to post handler success response. Http response code: 400.
Error: Runtime exited with error: exit status 128
Runtime.ExitError
```

In my Digitalocean Mongodb logs, I sometimes see this:

```
03-15-2024 4:51:27 PM mydb.mongo.ondigitalocean.com | Authentication failed
03-15-2024 4:51:27 PM mydb.mongo.ondigitalocean.com | No SSL certificate provided by peer
```

Again, not sure if this is relevant. The logs on Digitalocean are literally constantly logging something, including the above (even when I am not doing anything).

This indicates a error with Mongodb? Now I want to stress that the request fails immediately. It **does not** time out after 7,5 seconds. It is instant (100 - 200ms according to network tab).

I currently host my database on Digitalocean. I also tried a [Mongodb Atlas Vercel integration](https://www.mongodb.com/developer/products/atlas/how-to-connect-mongodb-atlas-to-vercel-using-the-new-integration/), but I got the same errors.

The strangest thing is that I can keep refreshing the page, and it's just 50/50 if the request will fail with a 500 internal server error or succeed. The first few times it works, then it fails a few times with a status code 500, then it works again for a few times, etc.

What am I missing and what more can I do to debug this problem?

Comment: Try to add descriptive error messages in all cases where `throw new Error(err);` is found. Like this: `throw new Error("Connecting to database failed.", { cause: err });` This can narrow down the location of the source of the error.

Answer (score 1):

There are few things happening, so let's take it one at a time.

#### The symptom: "Unexpected token '<'"

It's a typical error when a client assumes the response is a JSON and tries to parse it without checking. https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/issues/5861 describes it in details, but TL;DR version is Vercel returns a "Server error" html page instead of JSON error. You can argue that the server should always respect the Content-Type of request header, or the client should always treat API responses as untrusted data and validate it, but reality is these best practices are quite laborious to follow, and they don't bring that much value while everything is working. I would ignore it and accept that there is not much useful information in the error message and you need to get details in the log, which you did perfectly:

#### The problem: Server selection timed out

The key part of the vercel log is:

```
  reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'ReplicaSetNoPrimary',
    servers: Map(1) {
      'db-cv-0fe05b80.mongo.ondigitalocean.com:27017' => [ServerDescription]
    },
```

It says that the mongodb driver https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/6.5/ failed to determine which server of the replicaset is primary. Now it may require a bit of explanation on how replication works. It's documented at https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/replication/, but essentially the nodejs driver is aware of mongodb server topology - it connects to all members of the replica set, keeps the TCP connections open and manages logical connections pool on js level.

Mongodb replica set usually has 1 primary, and 1 or more secondary members. The members are otherwise equal, and when something happens to the primary, it triggers an election - a process when healthy members of the replica set negotiate which one will become a new primary. Once a primary is elected, this information is communicated to the clients (the nodejs driver in the vercel app in this case). Clients need this information as by default it sends requests to the primary only. There are options to read from secondaries, but all writes go to the primary unconditionally.

The thing is the election may take some time, and sometimes it's stuck when stubborn members of the replica set cannot agree who wears the primary hat, or when there are not enough healthy members to negotiate with at the first place (it's your case - the `servers: Map(1)` means there is only 1 member left). The driver holds up and defers all Promises until mongo resolves it's democracy thing, and eventually gives up and admits the cluster is sick by throwing "MongoServerSelectionError" exception. The 7,500ms countdown starts from the moment when the driver realized the previous primary has gone, and paused all request to the cluster until the new primary reported to the driver.

#### The root cause: yet to be found

As described above there is nothing wrong with the code - it does exactly what it suppose to do in case of problems with the database. It's not clear what caused the replicaset to lose the primary and it's inability to elect a new one. The

> The logs on Digitalocean are literally constantly logging something

is exactly what you need to analyze to understand health issues with the DB. Although mongo is designed to automatically recover when a primary steps down, it shouldn't happen that often in a healthy replica set.

Maintenance of replica set might be quite challenging and time consuming process. This partially explains commercial success of Atlas, when you outsource these problems to mongo support team.